# Digital interface to regulate blender motor

Tags: digital-potentiometer, universal-motor

A typical blender uses a universal-type motor which has a knob to toggle between different taps on the field coil for different speed settings. I wish to replace the knob with a touch-screen or a push-button interface.

What is the cost-effective method to do the same? How do I digitally select the tapping on the field coil?
Do I still need tacho or back EMF if I do **not** require rpm control?

Edit 1: Motor specs:

- Voltage: 230V AC 50 Hz
- Power: 600-1000 W
- Torque: 0.3-0.8 Nm

Comment: Typical blender has triac based voltage controller.

Comment: This question is not very useful without a blender model number and a circuit diagram of the blender.

Comment: Cost-effective?  Perhaps relays to replace the switching action.

Comment: @VoltageSpike - I have a multi-tap transformer-type arrangement. Refer to the schematic in the answer to this question - https://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/592596/blender-universal-motor-speed-control

Comment: Please edit the question an include the information, if you are including an image or circuit from another question, then reference that question at the bottom of the image. It would be better if you could draw the circuit of the blender that you have, the other question isn't really a schematic